# Adding Knockout Template at run time empties HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, knockout.js

Adding knockout templates at runtime empties the HTML DOM

```
    var templateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplate = function (templateName, templateMarkup) {
        document.write("<script type='text/html' id='" + templateName + "'>" + templateMarkup + "<" + "/script>");
    };
    templateEngine.addTemplate("gridTable","<table></table");
```

All the earlier content goes and The DOM becomes

```
<html><head><script type="text/html" id="gridView"><table></table></script></head></html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write: calling `document.write` on a closed (loaded) document **automatically calls `document.open` which will clear the document**

Answer (score 1):

As @nemsev said,

> [eveloper.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write](http://eveloper.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write:%20calling%20document.write%20on%20a%20closed%20(loaded)%20document%20automatically%20calls%20document.open%20which%20will%20clear%20the%20document): calling document.write on a closed (loaded) document **automatically calls document.open which will clear the document**

So, I modified my code to,

```
    var templateEngine = new ko.nativeTemplateEngine();

    templateEngine.addTemplate = function (templateName, templateMarkup) {
        //document.write("<script type='text/html' id='" + templateName + "'>" + templateMarkup + "<" + "/script>");
        var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
        scriptTag.type = "text/html";
        scriptTag.id = templateName;
        scriptTag.innerHTML = templateMarkup;
        var node = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        node.appendChild(scriptTag);
    };

    templateEngine.addTemplate("gridTable","<table></table");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create separate div in your html structure and then load the template in that div. For instance you can use jquery for it.

```
$("#someDiv").append(templateMarkup);
```